# Compare two file listings to find identical files but ignore extensions

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, ls, diff

I'd like to find files with the wav extension having the same filename, only different in extension (which is mp3) in the same directory.

I tried the following structured command so far:

```
$ diff -s $(for i in *.wav; do echo "${i%wav}"; done) $(for i in *.mp3; do echo "${i%mp3}"; done)
diff: extra operand `abc(xyz'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

Comment: To diff the output you'll need to `<(for i in ....)` rather than `$(for i in)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `diff` the output of some commands, use [process substitution `<(...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) instead of command substitution `$(...)`. Otherwise that seems it should work.

`diff $(foo)` puts the output of `foo` on the command line of `diff`, while `diff` wants the name of a file to read. `diff <(foo)` arranges for the output of `foo` to be available from an fd, and gives `diff` a pathname that corresponds to the already-opened fd (`/dev/fd/NN`, might be system-specific).

---

Though reading the question again, maybe you'd just want to do something like this:

```
for f in *.wav ; do
    b=${f%.wav}
    if [ -f "$b.mp3" ] ; then echo "$b.mp3 exists" ; else
        echo "$b.mp3 missing" ; fi
done
```

That would tell if all `.wav` files in the directory have a corresponding `.mp3` file. (But wouldn't show any `.mp3` files that don't have a corresponding `.wav`, of course.)

Comment: Yes, it helped, but I expexted that the `-s` switch will report identical files, but it seems to do the opposite.

Comment: @xralf, oh, right, `diff` is meant to show the _differences_, not similarities. `-s` just adds an extra note in the output if the the source files are identical. By default it wouldn't output anything.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do what you have written in the script, but I tried to write some one-liner command first, because I need this comparison quite often, so I wondered if there would be an elegant one-line structured command.

Comment: I inspired and done it `for i in *.wav; do if [ -f "${i%wav}mp3" ]; then echo "$i"; fi done`

Comment: @xralf, yep. You could snip a couple of bytes by using `[ ... ] && echo ...`. Or just put the whole thing in a script or a function.